# Can one toggle same checkbox with multiple buttons/"for" attributes (in just html/css)

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, toggle

To avoid code duplication I would like to be able to toggle the same modal contact form hidden by a checkbox from multiple buttons/labels, is this possible in pure html/css? For example:

```
<button for="chk1">BTN 1</button>
...

<button for="chk1">BTN 2</button>
...

<div id="form-div">
  <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
  ... model form code
</div>

<button for="chk1">BTN 3</button>
...
```

Comment: have you tried ?

Comment: Yes of course, and at least it didn't work in my tests so naturally I wonder if there is some way without resorting to javascript and since I'm not an expert on html/css I'm asking here.

Comment: `for` is a specific attribute for `label`, not `button` nor links ;) It works but can confuse a user loosing track the selection ...